# How do I add a version number to Angular PWA App

Tags: angularjs, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA App that I packaged with https://www.pwabuilder.com into a msixbundle to deploy on the Windows Store.  I noticed the builder adds a version of 1.0.0.1 to the bundle.  I want to manual control the version for adding incremental updates to the store.  I see in the Angular Docs that version is mentioned ngsw-config.json docs.  But the docs https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config and adding

```
version: 1.0.1;
```

did not work.  Are they any examples of adding a version number to the ngsw-config.json file

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the windows version number has to be edited in the PWA Builder.

Windows Package Options All Settings